# Replicate MUI paper background image

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with Material-UI on my NextJS project, and wanted to know if is there a way to replicate the paper background-image on other components ? It will allow me to make some other components the exact same colors as Paper, because this background-image affect the color with a lighter effect.

EDIT: this effect seems to only occurs on dark mode

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some components like Card, Dialog, Menu (and more) already use Paper as an inner component, then they get its style. The best way to add it to your components is to just use Paper as a surface.

You can also [add variants](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#adding-new-component-variants) to Mui components - for example, you add `paper` variant to TextField, and there add the styles.

A simpler way (but not complete) is to directly add the `Mui-Paper` className to another component (it is not complete because there are other styles except `Mui-Paper`. To achieve the elevation `background-image` effect you mantioned, you should add `.MuiPaper-elevation{props.elevation}` className.